# How do I create a single background thread that awaits the completion of multiple async WCF calls?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

My scenario consists of a .NET 4.0 WCF service, called by a .NET 4.5 client wrapped in a class library.

The client calls the WCF service asynchronously, and displays any data it returns. That code is pretty standard stuff and looks like this:

```
Private m_Service As WcfService = Nothing

Public Event GetDataComplete As GetEventHandler

Public Sub GetData(bytes As Byte())

    m_Service = New WcfService()
    AddHandler m_Service.GetWcfDataComplete, AddressOf Service_GetWcfDataComplete
    m_Service.GetWcfData(bytes)

End Sub

Private Sub Service_GetWcfDataComplete(sender As Object, e As WcfService.GetWcfDataCompletedEventArgs)

    ' Process results from server...
    ' Signal completion.
    RaiseEvent GetDataComplete(Me, New GetEventArgs(New DataItem(e.Result)))

End Sub
```

Because the WCF service limits the data returned to 64k chunks I have to call the service multiple times until everything's been downloaded. Also, `' Process results from server...` does some processing that updates the UI with the returned data. Predictably, this does horrifical things to the UI thread.

Hence the question in the title - how do I create a single background thread that awaits the completion of multiple async WCF calls?

Things I've tried but have failed:

- Using the `Async/Await` pattern. Visual Studio says that byte arrays are non-awaitable. I've no idea how to hack my way out of that one.
- Using `BackgroundWorker`. Using this approach I can't figure out how to signal the end of the process. Because the WCF call uses call-backs, I no longer have access to `DoWorkEventArgs` when the WCF service call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, this doesn't technically constitute an answer. This site limits the amount of text I can put into a comment so I've posted this as an answer instead.

So:

I've played around with various approaches. The ideal solution seems to be a full-blown multi-threaded model that blocks until the async call returns. It seems a *really* heavy-handed approach when the thread may not live for more than a second or two (assumes good comms to server), but in rare occasions may live for minutes. It has to be a blocking thread because in the async model a background worker would just die after the call to the server is made, and before the call's callback is fired.

The solution I'm using for now is to place all data coming down from the server into a queue, and kicking off a background worker when the queue has items. The background worker saves the items to the database, and then adds the items to the model, which in turn fires events that update the UI.

The queue approach has a serious flaw in that if the app is terminated after everything's been downloaded, but before the background worker has managed to dequeue and process all the items, those items are lost to the client because the server assumes them to have synced.

All approaches to solving that one strike me as messy (e.g. calling back to the server once dequeued and saved, to confirm sync, or to save, and then enqueue and process), so any other suggestions are still very welcome.

Comment: instead of an answer perhaps this should have been added to the question?